# Sequence of measurable functions on finite measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am struggling to solve the following exercise:

> Let $E \subset \mathbb R^d$ be finite measurable and $(f_k)_{k \geq 1}:E \to \mathbb R$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that for all $x \in E$, there is $M_x \in \mathbb R_{>0}$:$$ |f_k(x)|\leq M_x, \space \forall k \in \mathbb N$$
>
> Show that for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $F\subset E$ closed and $M>0$:$$ |E \setminus F| <\epsilon, \space \text{and}\space |f_k(x)|\leq M, \space \forall k \in \mathbb N, \space \forall x \in F$$

I got stuck at some point but this is what I thought of:

Let $(E,\mathcal M_{E},m_{E})$, then it is easy to see that $E=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} (\bigcap_{k \geq n} \{x \in E: |f_k(x)|\leq n\})$, note that $E_n= \bigcap_{k \geq n} \{x \in E: |f_k(x)|\leq n\}$ forms an increasing sequence of measurable sets. Then $\emptyset=\bigcap_{n\geq 1} (\bigcup_{k \geq n} \{x \in E: |f_k(x)|>n\})$. Since $m(E)<\infty$, $$0=\lim_{n \to \infty} m((E_n)^c)$$

Given $\epsilon>0$, there is $N: m((E_N)^c)<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$. Since $E_N$ is measurable, there exists a closed set $F \subset E_N$ with $\mu(E_N \setminus F)<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$. But then $m(E\setminus F)<\epsilon$ and $$|f_k(x)|\leq N, \space \forall x \in F, \space \forall k\geq N$$

I need this to work for all $k \geq 1$, I don't know what to do with the remaining $1,...,N-1$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest fix is to replace your $\bigcap_{k \geq n}$ with $\bigcap_{k \geq 1}$.

Comment: You can also let $g(x) = \sup_k |f_k(x)|.$ Then $g:E \to [0,\infty)$ is measurable. Consider the sets $E_n = \{g<n\}.$

Comment: Thanks guys!, I like your approach @zhw., shorter than mine.